# How can I fill a plane without gaps with regular squares?

Tags: processing

I'm new to processing, and trying to do this task. Maybe you know how to do it, or know where I could read about it.

I need something like this:

[image: link]

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What have you tried? What's not working? Where are you stuck? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image is a 4x3 grid with zero spacing between the columns(vg) and rows(hg):

```
final int _numRows = 3;
final int _numCols = 4;

void rectGrid(int l, int t, int w, int h, int hg, int vg) {
  int left;
  int top;
  for (int k = 0; k < _numRows; k++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < _numCols; j++) {
      left = l + j*(w+vg);
      top = t + k*(h+hg);
      stroke(0);
      strokeWeight(2);
      fill(255);
      rect( left, top, w, h);
    }
  }
}

void setup() {
  size(640, 340);
  background(209);
  rectGrid(20, 20, 150, 100, 0, 0);
}
```